# removing dynamically generated table rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a dynamically created table named "jobTable" based on some text inputs and a button and also save the data into an array at the same time. Each row of the table contains a button which is used to remove the entire row and update the array. Whenever a user tries to delete a row, the row will be correctly deleted but the array will be completely flushed and I lose all of the data. I guess it must be because of that all of the dynamically generated buttons share the same 'id' so the button's selector's function will be invoked more than one time, but it works fine on the table itself! Why is this happening?

```
var workExperience = [];
  $("#jobTable").on('click', '#DeleteRow', function () {
                    $removeditem = $(this).closest('tr').parent().index();
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    delData($removeditem);
                });

                function delData($x) {

                    workExperience.splice($x - 1, 1);
                    console.log(workExperience); //the array will be flushed in a few steps!
                }


$("#save").click( function () {

//Save the data into an array inorder to send it to the server later.
 workExperience.push($("#companyName").val());

//Append data into some table in order to make the user able to see or remove each row he/she enters

        $("#jobtable").append(
            "<tbody>" +
            "<tr>" +
            "<td>" +
            "<button type='button' id='DeleteRow'>"+
            "</td>" +
            "<td>" +
             $("#companyName").val() +
            "</td>" +
           "</tr>" +
            "</tbody>");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I lack the reputation to make this a comment, but could you please provide some more information on your HTML?

Alternatively if you don't mind adding a library. Knockout.js could handle this. See [this tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would like to store data at two places and try to maintain on delete button click.
Creating delete button with same ID is not good idea either.

I took a liberty and put together example for storing data into data- attribute for each company. I have stored just string into "data-workExp", but you can pretty much add any object like array. Here is the entire code for you:

```js
    $(function () {
        $("#jobtable").on('click', '.DeleteRow', function () {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });

        $('#toServer').click(function () {
            $('#serverData').html("");
            $('.CompanyRow').each(function () {
                $('#serverData').append("<div>" + $(this).data("workExp") + "</div>");
            });
        });

        $("#save").click(function () {
            $("#jobtable").append(
                $('<div>').addClass('CompanyRow').data('workExp', $("#companyName").val())
                    .html($("#companyName").val() + "<input type='button' class='DeleteRow' value='Delete Me'>")
            );
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
        <input id="companyName" type="text"><br />
        <input type="button" id="save" value="Save">
        <input type="button" id="toServer" value="Save to server!"/>
    </div>
    <div id="jobtable" >
    </div>

    <h1>Data goes to server</h1>
    <div id="serverData"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you man but my problem was deleting the deleted row's data from #server (as you named it). So do you have an advise about that?

Comment: The button with ".DeleteRow" class is taking care of deleting data from "#serverData".
The code snippet sends a data to server based on data in #serverData div.

Comment: Okay I got it, Thanks for the idea. "I am not sure why you would like to store data at two places..." Answer: The reason was that I actually didn't feel safe to read such sensitive data from a view because it can cause browser type dependency for the entered data which may damage data if some user uses an out-dated or non-standard non utf-8 supportive web browser. Not sure about that anyway, isn't it?